# Geoserver GetLegendGraphic for a layer group shows duplicate styles for all of its layers

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to get the legend for a Geoserver layer group using a GetLegendGraphic request.  This layer group contains 50+ layers, all of which use the same style.  As expected, the returned image contains the legend for that style, repeated 50 times.  Does anyone know of any way to force geoserver to *group* identical styles in the legends?

Comment: What type of group are you using? ~ https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/webadmin/layergroups.html I have a feeling that it you use NamedTree mode you can set a legend for the group layer

Comment: @nmtoken Doesn't seem to have any effect on the legend, unfortunately.  Additionally tried choosing one layer, zero layers, and all layers as "Default Style" in the Layer Group to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this comes late but I tested a workaround and worked for me since we've at work the same problem.

I changed the layer group mode attribute to **Earth Observation tree**, this will show in the configuration page another option for choosing the **root layer** of the group.

If all layers in the group have the same styles, by selecting one of them as root layer will expose only its attributes including its legend instead of the rest.

Source: https://docs.geoserver.org/2.22.x/en/user/data/webadmin/layergroups.html#layer-group-modes